# Which is faster creating multiple list or creating an object list?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I'm playing with 3 types of data to be inserted in a list. I'm wondering which is faster.
Should I create 3 different lists or should I create an object list which have 3 variables in it?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  This kind of micro-optimization is meaningless for performance.  You should write the code so it reads as clearly and uses the best object encapsulation practices as possible.

Comment: i think the 2nd option is better. tomorrow you want to play with 4th or 5th data do want to end up creating 2 more lists or just create 2 variables inside the object and values 2 these objects. mind tickling right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  This kind of micro-optimization is *meaningless* for performance.

You should write the code so it reads clearly and uses the best object encapsulation practices possible.

I would vote for better encapsulation - if those three disparate data types belong together, it's usually  best to make that clear by encapsulating them in a single object so you can manage their state together.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what you want from it - if they are directly related and you only use the 3 data types together then , stick them in an object and create getters/setters for them.

If you need to access them independently then 3 separate lists may be better.

Before considering speed you should consider the functionality - there is no point storing 3 completely unrelated data types together.